# standard error of outcome in lm and lme

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, nlme

I have the following linear models

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
fm2.lm <- lm(distance ~ age + Sex,data = Orthodont)
```

How can I obtain the **standard error of distance** with age and Sex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `fm2` (linear mixed model), you can do

```
sqrt(diag(summary(fm2)$varFix))
#(Intercept)         age   SexFemale 
# 0.83392247  0.06160592  0.76141685
```

For `fm2.lm` (linear model), you can do

```
summary(fm2.lm)$coefficients[, "Std. Error"]
#(Intercept)         age   SexFemale 
# 1.11220946  0.09775895  0.44488623
```

Answer (score 0):

see `attributes(summary(your.model))`. what you're after is `summary(your.model)$coefficients` (or did I get your question wrong?). just use subsetting with `[]` to get what you want

Comment: No thats not what I mean. The coefficients show you the change of the mean of the outcome with the change in the independent variables. I want to get the **st.error of the outcome** at the various values of the dependent variables. Not the estimates (coefficients and st.errors of the independent variables.

Comment: wait. I'm puzzled. since you're not estimating dependent variable as a coefficient, isn't standard deviation that you're after? I mean, if I understand it correctly, you want to see what is the variance of distance with respect to different combination of age and sex. so you don't need to use regression to find this out. you need sample standard deviations for different combinations of age and sex, no?

Comment: @ECII; You can get st. errors of the predicted line ?predict. And http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq